# Connect Existing Azure Ubuntu VM using SSH

Tags: ssh, azure

I have got access to have Azure VM (Ubuntu). Now, I wanna connect using SSH (Putty). From Azure portal I see,

[image]

I am very noob in ubuntu. I don't know in Azure where the Login-user-name kept and where they kept the pem file.

I tried to use Putty but after entering IP and port then Putty asking user-name which I dunno from where I can get. I have Azure portal with me.

Note: The apps in VM are running fine but dunno how to connect. So, it already setup.

**Update:** Can I rest password or certificate of VM in Azure as I don't have access

Comment: If you are using a pre-built VM (you did not run the Ubuntu installer yourself), try username `Ubuntu` and password `Ubuntu`. If they work, then your first task is obviously to create a new admin user with a different name and strong key-based ssh credentials. Once properly set up and tested, you can use the new account to delete the `Ubuntu` user -- there is nothing special about that user, and you don't want other folks logging into it!

Comment: @user535733 this was managed by another guy which I cannot contact but I do have Azure access, then what should I do?

Comment: I mean how can I connect the VM if I have access to Azure(if possible)?